# wget/curl how to overwrite HTML file if file content has changed?

Tags: html, curl, wget

I am creating a script to scrape numerous html files in a website, but I want it to be reusable and faster. so after downloading all the html files when I rerun it again it should just check if the html file content is different and if it is different then it will download the html else it will ignore it.

Is this possible?

I have tried to use:

```
wget --no-clobber
```

but `--no-clobber` only checks if the file exists.

Answer (score -1):

Make a HEAD request to the url using curl (`curl --head`). If the server returns the Last-Modified header (i.e. `Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT`) in response then compare it with your file's last update date to decide further. If that header is not in the response then you have to download it.